# MVC: Return .xlsx file as saved download rather than opening in Excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mime-types, epplus

I'm generating an Excel file using EPPlus and I want the user downloading the file to be prompted to save it rather than have the file immediately open in Excel.  How can I do this in MVC?

Here's my current code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DownloadData()
    {
        byte[] excelData = ExportService.GetServiceTrackerDataAsExcelData();
        return File(excelData, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", String.Format("ServiceTrackerData-{0}.xlsx", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
    }
```

Comment: actually what you are doing is right, the last param you are passing is the file name, as a result it should show the save as dialog. Have you tried this with different browsers or on different computers, probably there is a tool installed on the client and that is the reason.

Comment: try setting content type as application/octet-stream

Comment: my guess is that you somehow unchecked the "always ask before opening this type of file" once and now it directly opens instead of showing you the download dialog? to get rid of that right-click once on the download link, save target as and there check "always ask before opening this type of file"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

You're telling the browser already that the file is an attachment and therefore the browser will handle it externally. By default most browsers will display a dialog asking to open or save. However, users can choose to set Excel files to open automatically (often a checkbox to 'automatically do this next time'). If the user chose to open automatically in excel, then you can't override that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ServiceTrackerData.xslx")
```

Comment: That causes a "Duplicate headers received from the server" error in my browser. How would I suppress the original header generated by MVC in that instance?

Comment: In fact it turns out that that header is already the exact header produced by my original code any way.